# How to make R TableOne package work in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use tableOne package within shiny app. However, when I deploy the app, the output from tableOne packages only shows text table in the console instead of UI. The third tab which is generate using table1 package prints out normally. As you can see the second tab in this app:  https://chopdsbu.shinyapps.io/Shinytable1/

I did try using verbertimtextOutput/htmlOutput but all seems to cause R session abortion.Kableone function in this app failed to work.  Really appreciated if someone can provide insights regarding this.

Section Codes for UI:

```
tabPanel("selected",
              h3("Selection summary"),
              p(HTML("Basic summary")),
              # textOutput("summ"),
              textOutput("summ"),
              downloadLink('downloadData', 'Download table1')
```

section codes for server:

```
output$summ <- renderUI({
    df <- data.table(filedata())
    CreateTableOne(vars = tabvar,strata=groups(),data=df)
    tabone <-print(CreateTableOne(vars = tabvar,strata=groups(),data=df))
    write.csv(tabone,paste0('table1_',Sys.Date(),'.csv'))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I find using reactive to save Tableone printout to a data table and renderDataTable works. Hope this helps whoever come across similar problem.

```
 output$down <- renderDataTable(
     tablep()
    ,extensions = 'Buttons', 
    options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                   buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print'),
                   pageLength =50, rownames= T,autowidth=F)
  )
```